# textview text into array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to paste data into a text view, and i want this information to be placed into an array. At the moment that is all i need to do, later on i'm looking to place that data into a tableview. If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I have looked over the guidelines and understand what i did wrong i hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: Could someone tell me why my question is still on hold, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string from TextView using

```
NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *dataArray = [textViewString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];
```

Eg. Text pasted

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

result array would contain

`[@"Line 1",@"Line 2",@"Line 3"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str=@"Hi How r u"; 
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

if u want to make array of strring. please try this

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following

```
NSString *yourText = textView.text;//@"Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
NSArray *testArray = [yourText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```